# Comparing images with opencv is not working

Tags: python, opencv

I have an issue while running the code below.
The error is:

```
[ WARN:0@5.343] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) 
cv::findDecoder imread_('C:/PROJECT/Glycoma/images/dermquest/ROI - image211prime0.jpg_XHAulfB.png'): 
can't open/read file: check file path/integrity None 
[ WARN:0@5.350] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) 
cv::findDecoder imread_('C:/PROJECT/Glycoma/images/dermquest/ROI - image211prime0.jpg_XHAulfB.png'): 
can't open/read file: check file path/integrity 
[05/Apr/2022 12:51:22] "POST /PatientUploadImage/?id=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 10382
```

my code:

```
def PatientUploadImage(request):
    did = request.GET.get("id")
    pid = request.session["pid"]
    msg=""
    if request.POST:
        a = request.POST.get("det")
        if request.FILES.get("file"):
            myfile=request.FILES.get("file")
            fs=FileSystemStorage()
            filename=fs.save(myfile.name , myfile)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
            # from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
            # z=staticfiles_storage.url('media/LMM2_orig.jpg')
            
            print(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,''))
            filedata=os.scandir(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'images/dermquest'))
            
           
            for item in filedata:
                print(item.name)
            print("########################################################################")
            original = cv2.imread("C:/PROJECT/Glycoma/images/dermquest/"+filename)
            print(original)
            try:

                contrast = cv2.imread(os.path.join('C:/PROJECT/Glycoma/images/dermquest/')+filename)
                original = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                contrast = cv2.cvtColor(contrast, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                ss=compare_images(original, contrast, "Original vs. Contrast")
                
                msg="Detected"
            except:
                msg="Not detected"
```

Comment: Which compression/encryption format are you using while sending the image in the request?

Comment: "can't open/read file: check file path/integrity" - something with the spaces perhaps?

Comment: when you assign to variable then use spaces arounf `=` - it makes code more readable. See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you get in variables. Next you could check if you can open images in some Image Viewer/Editor. If image is broken then it can't be used in any function or tool.

Comment: your error shows name with `.jpg` and `.png` - which format has your file - if it is JPG and you add extension `.png` then it may have problem to read it.